# How to return a multidimensional array keys in tree format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, tree, key, multidimensional-array

How can I return multidimensional array keys in tree format in PHP?

For example, if I have the following array:

```
$array = array ( 
    array (
        'name' => 'A', 
        'product' => array (
            'qty' => 1,
            'brand' => 'Tim'
        ), 
        'goods' => array (
            'qty' => 2
        ), 
        'brand' => 'Lin'
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'B', 
        'product' => array (
            'qty' => 6,
            'brand' => 'Coff'
        ),
        'goods' => array (
            'qty' => 4
        ), 
        'brand' => 'Ji'
    )
);
```

How can I get a result like the following -- including no repeating of keys:

```
-name
-product
--qty
--brand
-goods
--qty
--brand
```

Comment: Hold on, you only want the keys printed, with no values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an unlimited depth you need a recursive function. I suppose you have the parents in $names and the childs in $children:

```
function render_select($root=0, $level=-1) 
{
    global $names, $children;
    if ($root != 0)
       echo '<option>' . strrep(' ', $level) . $names[$root] . '</option>';
    foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
       render_select($child, $level+1);
}
```

This functions use useful because you can feed it with 2 variables. The other answere requires a multidimensional array.

Comment: Global variables in functions are bad design and bad practice. They rely on the names of variables in the global scope, and make your function un-portable. `global` and `$GLOBALS` are much like `goto` - just because they are there, doesn't mean you should *ever* use them. There are rare exceptions to the rule, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Typo3 uses a lot of global variables. Can you say constants are better then global variables?

Comment: Most problems "fixed" by functional programming languages and object oriented programming languages relate to encapsulating data and having a clear path of "where the data came from", "where it was modified last", "how was it modified". Procedural code had the downside that by using `global` and `goto` you can accidentally get the result of changing the global variables at moments when you expected them to keep their state. Hence the behavior of the application changes.

Comment: Constants are `constant` globals are `global` you don't compare apples to oranges.

Comment: Constants are different from variables, as they hold *constant* (never changing) *scalar* values. For a job like this, you want to pass the array to the function, and have a single argument that passes through the recursion to track the current depth.

Comment: Also you can't define constant arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions should cover any depth you want/need:

```
 function print_tree($tree, $level = 0) {
     foreach($tree AS $name => $node) {
         if(
               is_scalar($node) OR
               (
                   is_object($node) AND
                   method_exists($node, '__toString')
               )
           ) {
             echo str_repeat('-', $level).$name.': '.$node;
         }
         else if(
                   is_array($node) OR
                   (
                       is_object($node) AND
                       $node InstanceOf Traversable
                   )
                ) {
             echo str_repeat('-', $level).$name.":\n";
             print_tree($node, $level+1);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it. However, maybe you would want to print a string-representation of non-scalar values.

Comment: I added the extra checks for string-able objects and for array-able objects

Comment: Printing something like [object of class X] would be useful for objects with no __toString method. And resources. Iterator extends traversable, so that doesn't need to be included.

Comment: And AFAIK, objects which just implement ArrayAccess aren't traversable using foreach.

Comment: I thought Traversable is only used by internals. I don't agree that printing [object ClassName] is better first of all because we're not creating a print_r/var_dump analysis function, just a tree printer for circumstances when you have for example **categories** and such in a tree.

Comment: Traversable cannot be directly implemented, but any object that can be traversed with foreach has it in it's inheritance chain.

Comment: You should actually avoid the use of `OR` and `AND`, they are **NOT** synonyms of `&&` and `||` and behave differently (the precedence rules are different) and may conduct to bad practices if not used when properly.

Comment: I am aware of those differences and I prefer lower precedence operators for easier logical grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
function print_tree($array, $level=1) {
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if(is_array($element)) {
            print_tree($element, $level+1);
        } else {
            print str_repeat('-', $level).$element."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should first check if the value `is_scalar` because it is more likely for it to be a scalar and it takes less time to check if it's a scalar vs. testing if it's an array/object.

Comment: IMO, printing a string-representation of values that are non-array & non-scalar is more desirable than omitting them completely.

Comment: That's true but you can't print an object that doesn't have a __toString method can you? so you should check to make sure.

Comment: See my comments on your answer.